# Azure Authorization Failed Error: The client 'XXXXX' with object ID 'XXXXX' does not have authorization to perform action 'XXXXX' over scope 'XXXXX'

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to log a model from Azure Databricks notebook to Azure Machine Learning and encountered this `Authorization Failed Error`. These two services are actually linked together for [dual tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-mlflow-azure-databricks?tabs=cli%2Cmlflow#dual-tracking-on-azure-databricks-and-azure-machine-learning).
Strangely enough, Azure Databricks has permissions to log model experiments on Azure ML, but not register models.

```
(AuthorizationFailed) The client '<Number>' with object ID '<Number>' does not have authorization 
to perform action 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/models/read' over scope '<path>' or scope is invalid. 
If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

[image: Error message on Databricks]

Would anyone know what permission granting I should be doing? Or would using a service principal better?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**
What was needed is to create a role for the Azure Databricks generated managed identity `dbmanagedidentity` over the scope of the Azure Machine Learning resource.

There's two ways to do it, one with UI, the other with Azure CLI.

**Steps with UI:**

1. Go to my Azure Machine Learning resource and go to the Access Control tab (IAM).
2. Click on "Add role assignment".
   [image: AML Access Control Page]
3. Select the right role permission (good practice is to select the minimum needed). In my case, Contributor was good enough.
4. Select "Managed Identity" and find the Databricks' workspace associated managed identity.
   [image: Add Permission for selected managed identity]
5. Click "review and assign" and this is it! Your Databricks has now permission to your AML resource.

**Another way with Azure CLI:**

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id <Databricks Managed Identity Object Id> --role Contributor --scope <AML Scope>
```

The full command would look like this:

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id 22222222-dddd-cccc-dddd-aaaaaaaa --role Owner --scope /subscriptions/your-subscription-id/resourceGroups/your-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/your-aml-name
```

Your Databricks Object ID is the managed identity one (also it is the one that appears in the error). You can find the AML Scope in the IAM page, on the "Assign and Review" tab:
[image: AML Scope]